# Dual boot on Hp Envy Ultrabook

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-7, hp, ssd

I just bought a HP Envy ultrabook 1002TX. It comes with a Win7 Home basic and a 32GB SSD + 500GB HDD.

I started to install ubuntu and in doing so went and deleted all the partitions on my HDD and recreated them the way I wanted.

Then when I tried to install ubuntu it didn't recognize my HDD. To solve this i typed `dmraid -E -r /dev/sdX` where the 'X' was my SSD drive. After this ubuntu can install but windows for some reason does not install. Also the Intel Caching feature is lost and SSD is just sitting and doing nothing.

I want to know how to solve this problem. Ideeally I would like to use the SSD for caching, either in windows or ubuntu. 
How do I get the SSD back to working as an Intel rapid cache?
How do I get windows to install properly? It tell me that windows is unable to configure itself to my hardware, and my PC came with windows pre-installed so this is not possible.

Sorry for the long question and thanks for your answers!

PS:
At one time when I booted I pressed `Ctrl+i` and went to the intel rapid cache menu. I think i screwed up something in here, because only after this the rapid cache stopped working, and each time I booted the PC thought the BIOS was my primary disk.

Answer (score 2):

I did a

```
dmraid -E -r /dev/sda
dmraid -E -r /dev/sdb    <-- ssd
```

Then installed Linux onto the SSD, and used the 500GB(SDA) for my /home folder. It's not a perfect solution (not using caching), but at least using the SSD to startup super fast etc.

It's a step in the right direction at least!

Comment: hmm. ya.. but i wanted to use the SSD for caching. I initially thought that I would partition it and cache both win and ubuntu on it. Gave up on this as for some reason win doesn't want to do caching. trying to get it to only work with atleast ubuntu now. Btw, do you have a dual boot on the exact same laptop? I want to ask you some questions on the drivers u used etc.

Comment: I gave up on dual boot, I couldn't get Windows 8 to see any drives. I may work on dual boot later and put Win8 all on the 500gb.

Comment: Okay. I am also trying the same thing right now. Win 7 all on HDD. SSD for ubuntu cache (hopefully!)

Comment: Have you been able to get the audio to work in ubuntu 12.04

Comment: I have an Envy 4, and the audio worked out of the box. Speakers and headphones. The only issues I had were with the WiFi (fixed with DEB), weird TX Dropped Errors (fixed with a line of code), and the brightness issue (fixed by setting brightness at boot). Everything else works oob. I haven't tried working with Windows on the 500gb yet though.

Comment: Is it the ultrabook version. (are there two versions also?) Mine is the ENVY 4 ultrabook 1002TX and sound is just not working. :(

Comment: @JohnnyFive how did you fix the wifi issue? mine is not detecting

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me:

1. Turn off acceleration in the Intel Rapid Storage Tech. It will take a while.
2. Click reset to available (it will show up once you disable acceleration) which should remove the fake raid thing and free your SSD.
3. Use some disk utility such EaseUs, to turn your HP Recovery and HP_Tools partitions to logical. Now, you should have atmost 3 primary partitions. If not, then make sure that you don't have more than 3 by changing to logical/removing unnecessary partitions that you may have created. Create some unallocated space from one/more of the partitions. ~10GB is good. DO NOT CHANGE BOOT PARTITION TO LOGICAL.
4. Restart and enter BIOS, turn off the Intel Rapid Start Tech.
5. Install using live USB by selecting "Something Else" in the unallocated space.
6. Now, you may turn on Intel Rapid Storage and Intel Rapid Start. The exact same config in the Intel Rapid Storage cannot be restored so what you could do is make 18.6GB cache volume and the rest data volume. From that data volume, you could turn 4GB into hibernation partition using command prompt and use the rest for storing any files that you access frequently. Use enhanced mode now instead of the maximized mode, just to be safe. If Linux and Windows both use SSD for cache and you use maximized mode then you'd most likely have trouble.

Apparently, there is no way to put back the same config of 4GB data(hibernation) volume and 26GB cache volume.

All this may seem to be out of the blue and look like as if I am talking about random stuff but if you have googled enough, you'd know what I am talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same laptop and the same problem. Presently after a lot of Rnd, I was able to partition the HDD and then load Windows. Remember *not* to format the SSD which has the OEM,  that is essential for backup and any OS loading.

The problem is that the default BIOS in the system is not complete, actually what is hidden is the `uefi`. Check this [link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/45567380/how_to_install_Ubuntu_on_HP_Envy-4_ultrabook.pdf).

So as it stands I am searching the net for a solution. Actually I even contacted HP. They said they will get back. Nothing as yet.

Comment: the document explains just how to get ubuntu 12.04 running. Nothing about dual boot.

Comment: Have you been able to get audio to work in ubuntu 12.04?